# Wpf - Tooltip : ItemsSource not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have an Expander in a UserControl and i have set the tooltip as below

```
 <Expander.Header >
            <Border Background="#cccccc"  Margin="2 8 8 8" Height="52"  >
                <Border.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip >
                        <ToolTip.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#cccccc"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ToolTip.Resources>
                        <Border Background="#4d4d4d" BorderThickness="0.5"  CornerRadius="5" MinWidth="200">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <!--#region Details -->
                                <WrapPanel Grid.Column="1"  Margin="8">
                                    ...
                                    <TextBlock Margin="4" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                                     ...
                                 </WrapPanel>
  <!--#endregion--> 

  <!--#region Previews images-->
                                    <Border Grid.Column="0"   BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0 0 0.5 0" MinHeight="200">
                                        <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PanelCardToolTip}"  ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ListVoci,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"  MinWidth="120"  >
                                        <!--<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PanelCardToolTip}"  ItemsSource="{Binding}"  MinWidth="120"  >-->

                                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                    <WrapPanel />
                                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>

                                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                                        </ItemsControl>
 </Border>

                                    <!--#endregion-->
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </ToolTip>
                    </Border.ToolTip>
 </Border>
            </Expander.Header>
```

the datatemplate is as follows:

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="PanelCardToolTip">
        <Border Background="#4d4d4d"  BorderBrush="#cccccc" BorderThickness="0.5" Width="55">
            <StackPanel Margin="8" Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="Static Text" Foreground="White"></TextBlock>

                <Image Margin="2" Source="{Binding PathImgAnteprima}" Width="30"/>
                <TextBlock   FontWeight="Medium" Margin="2 4 2 2" Text="{Binding Etichetta}"/>
                <TextBlock   FontWeight="Light" Margin="2 0 2 2" Text="{Binding Descrizione}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <!-- CardView -->
    </DataTemplate>
```

The problem is that the ItemsSource of ItemControl not working (as if ItemsSource is not visible to DataContext, but it is visible ). 
The same ItemsControl with same ItemsSource and DataTemplate work fine in a panel outdoor the Tooltip and inside Expander.

Thanks so much
M.P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[RESOLVED]** - The real problem is `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}. The final solutione as below

```
   <Border Grid.Column="1"   BorderBrush="#cccccc" BorderThickness="0.2 0 0 0" MinHeight="200">
   <ItemsControl  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PanelCardToolTip}"  ItemsSource="{Binding ListVoci}"  MinWidth="120"  >
       <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <WrapPanel />
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   </ItemsControl>
```

Another operation that i have made it's to write **Itemscontrol** out of Expander.Header's tag.

Thanks all
M.P.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the Tag property of the Border element to the DataContext of the window and then bind to the Tag property of the PlacementTarget of the ToolTip:

```
<Expander.Header>
    <Border Background="#cccccc"  Margin="2 8 8 8" Height="52"
                        Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
        <Border.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip>
                <ToolTip.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#cccccc"/>
                    </Style>
                </ToolTip.Resources>
                <Border Background="#4d4d4d" BorderThickness="0.5"  CornerRadius="5" MinWidth="200">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Border Grid.Column="0"   BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0 0 0.5 0" MinHeight="200">
                            <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PanelCardToolTip}"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.ListVoci,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip}}" MinWidth="120">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <WrapPanel />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ToolTip>
        </Border.ToolTip>
        <TextBlock>....</TextBlock>
    </Border>
</Expander.Header>
```

The reason why you cannot bind to a property of the parent window in a ToolTip using a RelativeSource binding is that the ToolTip resides in its own visual tree.

Answer (score 0):

the other elements such as `Text="{Binding **Description**}"` are correctly accessible and works fine. The problem is only on ItemsSource that not iterate the list.

With `<ToolTip DataContext="{Binding DataContext` on the Tooltip,  does not work either field `Text="{Binding **Description**}"`

Comment: Did you read my answer? Try to bind the Tag property of the Border element to the DataContext of the window and then bind to the Tag property of the PlacementTarget of the ToolTip.

Comment: yes, i have tried to use tag property but does not work fine. Thank you very much for your availability

Comment: Can you please post the definition of the class where the ListVoci and Description are defined?

Comment: ListVoci is an ObservableCollection<Voci> that is defined in a MyViewModel class.. MyViewModel is the DataContext of MainWindow.xaml and the embedded User Controls.

Description is a public property of MyModel Class. 

In this case, the Expander is a part of UserControl included in a DataTemplate used in a ListView

Answer (score 0):

- **Description** is a public property of MyModel Class.
- **ListVoci** is an `ObservableCollection<Voci>` of MyModel Class.
- **MyViewModel** is the DataContext of MainWindow.xaml and the embedded User Controls.
- **`ObservableCollection ListComm<MyModel>`** is the itemssource of a ListView

In my case, the Expander is a part of UserControl included in a DataTemplate used in a ListView

the code are written below

```
<ListView 

            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PreviewCTemplate}"  
            ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ListComm, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"  
            SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedComm, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"

        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
```